# How to prevent sessionStorage from showing in JavaScript console?

Tags: javascript, session, security

I would like to store some sensitive information in sessionStorage to use it across multiple pages.

However anyone with a minimal Javascript knowledge can open browser's JavaScript console, type sessionStorage with dot at the end and see all its fields and subsequently all fields' content.

So actually sessionStorage is absolutely not safe, meaning I cannot store there any sensitive information like user ID, password, etc. 
Or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you not use server side sessions to store the sensitive data across pages?

Comment: Actually I can, It is just sessionStorage seems an easier and a faster way. IMHO this drawback decreases sessionStorage usability drastically.

Comment: That's why you don't store sensitive data on anything the client has access to. It was never intended for that purpose as it's a fairly open API, which is good because it makes it easy to use.

Comment: Can you explain why is it a problem if a user sees **his own** id, or **his own** password?

Comment: In case some users/family members share the same computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safe in what context? It's storage for client data, so as long as the data doesn't leak between websites you're good to go. Of course sessionStorage **wasn't designed** to keep any data you want to hide from your user (**especially sensitive** information!) so don't be surprised that any data you put there is easily available to him.

Use other means to store such sensitive information (preferably server side storage where it's presumably more safe).